# EF 5 - Unable to determine if an entity is attached

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to determine if an EF 5 entity is attached as follows:

First this method is called:

```
public bool IsAttached(object entity)
{
    EntityKey entityKey = GetEntityKey(entity);

    if (entityKey == null)
        return false;

    return IsAttached(this.AsObjectContext(), entityKey);
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
public EntityKey GetEntityKey(object entity)
{
    ObjectStateEntry objectStateEntry;
    if (null != entity && this.AsObjectContext().ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out objectStateEntry))
    {
        return objectStateEntry.EntityKey;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If the IsAttached() method return false, this method is called:

```
        var attachedEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `IsAttached()` method always returns false, because `GetEntityKey()` returns null, even when the object is already attached. IOW, even when an entity is attached, I can't get the entity key, which causes the whole thing to fail. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using EF 5, not code first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the majority of that code ... just use

```
if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
```

Comment: This line of code fails too. When I execute this, it tells me the entity is detached, but when I go to attach it, I get an error saying an object with the same key exists in the object manager.

Comment: Could be. Do you know how an entity key is generated?

Comment: No sorry - you have your entity and know the key - do a find on the `Set<>()` and take it from there ...

Comment: Oh, so the entity key is the primary key?